# How to Dynamically Add Metadata to JWT Tokens in Supabase for Same User when signing in from Different Platforms

Tags: supabase, supabase-js

I am working on a project with two platforms, a Mobile App and an Admin App, both using Supabase for user authentication. I want to control data access for users based on the platform they are signed in from, using Row Level Security (RLS) policies in Supabase.

My goal is to add metadata to the JWT token when a user is created, specifying the platform they are signing in from. I've attempted to achieve this by including the metadata in the options section during user sign-in, as shown below:

```js
  const { data: OTPData, error: OTPError } =
    await supabaseClient.auth.signInWithOtp({
      phone: `91${phoneNo}`,
      options: {
        shouldCreateUser: true,
        channel: "whatsapp",
        data: {
          app_metadata: { x: "admin" }, // Adding Meta Data here
        },
      },
    });
```

However, I've observed that this approach only adds metadata to new users in the authentication table, and the metadata is included in the JWT token regardless of whether the data option is provided or not.

I'm seeking guidance on how to dynamically add metadata to JWT tokens for users who have already been created, so that I can implement different RLS policies based on the platform they are signing in from. Any insights or suggestions on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can update app_metadata in a secure server-side environment using the auth admin: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-admin-updateuserbyid

```js
const { data: user, error } = await supabase.auth.admin.updateUserById(
  '6aa5d0d4-2a9f-4483-b6c8-0cf4c6c98ac4',
  { app_metadata: { x: "admin" } }
)
```